# Error importing modules in python using VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

So i have this scipt and i installed the needed modules which were pyautogui, pywin32 and keyboard.
Somehow, pyautogui is working as normal but I cant seem to be able to import the pywin32 and keyboard modules. I've tried everything, installed with "pip install pywin32", even "python -m pip install pywin32" and nothing. can anyone help me?
The script runs flawlessly in sublime text, this error only occurs in vscode.
thanks in advance

[Photo demonstrating the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7nfR.png)

Comment: maybe you have other `python` installed and you should use `/full/path/to/python` to install it with correct python

Comment: did you run this code? Image doesn't show `error` but only `warning` that `vscode` can't find information about modules - but it doesn't means `error` and code may works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, please try the following:

1. Please use the command "`pip list`" or "`pip show module_name`" to check whether this module is installed in the python currently used by the terminal.

   [image]
2. After installation, please reopen the python file or reload VS Code so that the module can be recognized.

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: thanks, it stills appears a yellow line under the win32api and win32con but it works someway

Comment: @LotusXvr -What language service do you use in VS Code? And what theme are you using in VS Code? Please try different VS Code [theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes). In addition, if the code can run, you could ignore this warning message.

Comment: @LotusXvr -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Comment: Well, it still appears the yellow line under the imports, but it only appears sometimes, I don't know why, but it works somehow. kind of annoying for them to appear but ey, it works at least